# How can I receive DragEvents of an ongoing drag for newly added Views?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-view

As far as I can tell, `View`s only receive `DragEvent`s if they had implemented `onDragEvent()` or had set an `OnDragListener` *before* `startDrag()` (or `startDragAndDrop()` for API 24+) is called. They will then continue to receive additional drag events if they return `true` for `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`.

However, I am looking for a way to receive `DragEvent`s *after* a drag operation had already started, for `View`s that got added to the layout *during* the drag operation.

---

To illustrate why, my situation is roughly the following:

I have a `ViewPager2` with `ListView` fragments whose list items can be dragged. If I drag an item over another item, I "enter" that item and a new `ListView` fragment is shown with new child items. This works fine.

However, since these new child items didn't exists at the time of starting the drag operation, they don't receive `DragEvent`s when I continue to drag the item over those new items.

So, basically, I want to be able to enter multiple levels deep in one continuous drag operation.

---

Is it possible to have newly added `View`s receive `DragEvent`s for an ongoing drag operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve it by re-dispatching the original `DragEvent` (the one with action `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`) to my main component, which is an instance of `ViewGroup`.

On inspecting the source code for `ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent()` I found that `ViewGroup` has a member variable called `mChildrenInterestedInDrag` that gets filled with children interested in drag events, when `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` is received.

So when I called `ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent()` with the original `DragEvent`, after I entered an item in the list to view its child items, those new `ListView` child items were now responding to additional `DragEvent`s.

I'm a bit worried that this approach might yield unexpected side effects. If I come across such effects upon further testing, I'll update this answer. But for now it will do.

If somebody knows that this *indeed* might yield unexpected side effects and/or has a better solution I'd love to hear them.

---

<sub>**Addendum:**</sub>

Upon storing the original `DragEvent` for re-dispatching, I had to "clone" the event, because, while it worked properly in an API 19 emulator, on an API 19 phone the original `DragEvent`'s action were continuously altered during dragging, so its action wouldn't reflect `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` anymore and re-dispatching didn't have the desired effect of registering newly added `View`s as interested in the ongoing drag operation.

Since `DragEvent`s cannot be cloned or constructed, I had to "clone" it with the help of a `Parcel`:

```java
void storeStartEvent(DragEvent startEvent) {
  Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
  startEvent.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
  // important to "rewind" the Parcel first
  parcel.setDataPosition(0);
  this.startEvent = DragEvent.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
}
```

Other than that, I didn't experience any noticeable problems yet, so it may have just solved my issue nicely.